# Firebase cloud messaging (FCM) Admin - is it okay to store the service account API keys in the local storage

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is it secure to simply save it in the local storage along with my project files? Or is it safer to store them as environment variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would in general advice against saving and pushing credential files into a repository for others to see.

You may consider encrypting you credential file. Everyone who has to work with the project then has to decrypt it first and you have control who receives the access to it.

Have a look Googles KMS: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-encrypt-with-kms/index.html#0